# 95% confidence interval error bars of normalized histogram

Tags: confidence-interval, normalization, histogram

I have observational data from a satellite and I am studying a certain phenomenon. I have locational data of these phenomena (let's call this data set A). I have divided the data into histogram bins of the same width along the x-axis. I am measuring the number of observations as a function of x-axis position. The data is normalized so that the sum of the bins is 1 and the bin heights represent probabilities.

On top of that I have control data (data set B) that consists of all the measurements made by the satellite, including the measurements that observed the phenomenon I am studying. So A is a subset of B. I plotted the same kind of histogram for B as for A. I normalized A by B (A/B) so I can see if the phenomenon occurs more on certain values of x, taking into account the orbital bias of the satellite.

I want to plot error bars for the normalized histogram. How should I do it? I have plotted error bars for data sets A and B individually with 95% binomial proportion confidence interval with the normal approximation

I have tried calculating the error bars for the normalized by getting the upper error limit by dividing the the highest value of the A bin by the lowest value of the B bin and the lower error limit by diving the lowest value of the A bin by the highest value of the B bin. I think the error bars look good, but I would like to know the proper way to do this.

I am new to statistics but willing to learn and read if you guys can help me out. Thanks!